# MongoDB slow queries using Motor driver

Tags: python, mongodb, motordriver

I have some troubles with Motor driver developing asyncio-based Python application.

Let me explain:

When I start Python process, Mongo queries through Motor driver run pretty fast: 0 to 1 milliseconds each.

Howewer, when process has been running for two minutes or so and some queries has been done, spent time in each query rise from 1ms to 200ms or even more.

Application code:

**Database connection**

```
async def init_pool(self, environment):
     try:
         mongo_config = self.config[environment]
         url = await self.build_url_connection(mongo_config=mongo_config)
         client = motor.motor_asyncio.AsyncIOMotorClient(url, serverSelectionTimeoutMS=mongo_config['timeout'])

         self.pool[environment] = client[mongo_config['database']]
     except:
         pass

async def get_pool(self):
    if 'admin' not in self.pool:
        await self.init_pool(environment='admin')
    return self.pool['admin']
```

**Read document method:**

```
async def read_single_document(filter, collection, projection=None):
    mongo_connection = await connection_obj.get_pool()
    mongo_client = mongo_connection[collection]
    result = await mongo_client.find_one(filter, projection)
    return result
```

**Spent time in logs:**

> 2021-07-27 12:33:52,355 INFO -- filter {'imei': 352625692901745} -- read_single_document -- 0 ms

> 2021-07-27 12:33:52,357 INFO -- filter {'imei': 352625692901745} -- update_single_document -- 0 ms

> 2021-07-27 12:41:01,090 WARNING -- filter {'imei': 352625692901745} -- read_single_document -- 688 ms

> 2021-07-27 12:41:01,307 WARNING -- filter {'imei': 352625692901745} -- update_single_document -- 208 ms

Database has correct indexes.

All time is spent in this line:

```
result = await mongo_client.find_one(filter, projection)
```

Any help about this behaviour?

Comment: Anything that takes more than 100ms should be in the mongod log.  See if that holds any clues.

Comment: Mongo log doesn't show any slow query. It seems there is something wrong with Motor driver

Comment: Try turning down the slowms on the server so everything gets logged.  Then you can compare how long the operations took on the mongod vs. how long motor reported.

Comment: I did something like that. I captured TCP traffic and showed in Wireshark how much time was spent only in MongoDb part without Motor. Time spent was never higher than 1ms. All time was spent in Motor for some reason.